# Holiday names from HolidayCalendar?

Tags: date-and-time

`HolidayCalendar` [doc](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HolidayCalendar.html?view=all) outputs aholiday dates as `DateObject` list based on a date range.

Is there a method or Entity to map to names, eg Christmas, 4th of July, &c?

Comment: Is this of any help: ``WolframAlpha["holidays 2022 USA", "DataRules"]``?

Comment: unfortunately we cannot access Alpha from our work network. Can you provide a sample as an answer?

Comment: A shortened output: ``{{{PublicObservance (country),1}, ComputableData} -> Saturday, January 1 : New Year's Day, {{PublicObservance (country), 2}, ComputableData} -> Monday, January 17 : Martin Luther King Jr. Day  (United States), <<95>>, {{ReligiousAndCulturalObservance, 32}, FormattedData} -> Saturday, December 31 : New Year's Eve}``, and [full output](https://pastebin.com/NsSTvkmq).

Comment: U.S. Federal holidays are specified by [`5 U.S. Code § 6103`](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/5/6103)

Comment: @Domen, the query specified 2022, why are results returned as generic Saturday, January 1 , rather than a date object or at least ISO string 2022-01-01? Is there an option for that? -- otherwise it's extra steps, potentially fraught w edge cases - to convert

Comment: @Domen, btw, your query is for USA, but it returns 98 holidays including China, Islam and others. And those that are in common have no parenthetical country - which means have to add regex. This is so bad, Alpha, what a joke. Seems easier to scrape https://www.calendar-365.com/holidays/2022.html

Comment: @alancalvitti, I never use [`WolframAlpha`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html) function but there are several options with which you can control the output. I've tried some, but I have not managed to get ``DateObjects`` – try playing around with various options. As for the number of holidays – it is not that bad actually! As you can see, they are separated into three categories: ``PublicObservance (country), InternationalObservance, ReligiousAndCulturalObservance`` so you can filter which category you want.

Answer (score 3):

One of the projects that I work recently was re-writing part of Mathematica calendrical calculations with some additional functionality. You can read [the article](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2434669) which I explained my journey, with benchmarks and a couple of suggestions and possible issues. I found the absence of a couple of functions one of which was the holiday name. Here is how it works (after loading `cDateFunctions.wl`):

```
cHolidayName[{2022, 7, 4}]
(* Out: "Independence Day" *)
```

Keep in mind day-offs:

```
cHolidayName[{2022, 12, 25}]
(* Out: Missing["Holiday"] *)

cHolidayName[{2022, 12, 26}]
(* Out: "Christmas Day's day off" *)
```

(The `c` in the beginning was added to distinguish the re-written function from Wolfram ones, like `cDayRange` instead of `DayRange` and etc)

> Due to my limited time and interest, this will only work on U.S. holidays (sources: timeanddate.com and britannica.com)

Before publishing it, I heavily tested the main functions against Wolfram Language but if you're going to use it in a real project, I encourage you to test it on your cases.

You can access the code on GitHub:
[github.com/ben-izd/cDateFunctions/blob/main/cDateFunctions.wl](https://github.com/ben-izd/cDateFunctions/blob/main/cDateFunctions.wl)

Holiday rules are included in the comment ([line 70](https://github.com/ben-izd/cDateFunctions/blob/c7008d32816a4614b710f78e973bac7cc8b49e06/cDateFunctions.wl#L70)).

In the article, more functions were demonstrated. You can read the article [Date-related functions: revision and performance comparison](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2434669) on Wolfram Community.

Answer (score 3):

Listening to the latest [Live CEOing](https://youtu.be/-TL6fFwuA2w?t=2670), I found out Mathematica had **Holiday Entities**. However, even though they have a property called `"DateFunction"`, you can apparently only retrieve dates for the current year.

```
holidayDates = 
  DayRange[DateObject[{2022, 1, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", 0], 
   DateObject[{2023, 1, 1}, "Day", "Gregorian", 0], "Holiday", 
   HolidayCalendar -> "UnitedStates"];

allHolidays = EntityValue[EntityClass["Holiday", "UnitedStates"], {"Name", "Date"}];

Grid[{#, StringJoin @@ Riffle[Cases[allHolidays, {name_, #} :> name], "; "]} & 
  /@ holidayDates, Alignment -> Left] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: All holidays]

Each holiday has an assigned type: `{"Cultural", "Whimsical", "Government", "Public", "Religious", "National", "International", "Health", "TaxDay"}`. We may want to remove whimsical holidays to get a more relevant list.

```
nonWhimsicalHolidays = 
 EntityValue[
  FilteredEntityClass[EntityClass["Holiday", "UnitedStates"], 
   EntityFunction[h, h["HolidayType"] != "Whimsical"]], {"Name", 
   "Date"}];

Grid[{#, StringJoin @@ Riffle[Cases[nonWhimsicalHolidays, {name_, #} :> name], "; "]} & 
  /@ holidayDates, Alignment -> Left] // TraditionalForm
```

[image: NonWhimsical Holidays]

---

Note that you can also get holidays for several other countries (much more than what `HolidayCalendar` supports). The total list is available with `EntityClassList["Holiday"]`.